# jQuery Dynamic form submission and Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

everything works, I get my json array returned in an alert,  I just need to change the onSubmit event handler `$('#city').submit(function()` to something more dynamic that grabs the user input and runs the ajax call as soon as the user types the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the keyup() event:

```
$("#term").keyup(function(e){

});
```

But you can also use the autocomplete function from JQuery-UI: [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Using autocomplete this would be:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({source: "/suggestjson", minLength: 2, select: function (event, ui) {
    //do something when the user selects, by the way the value 
    //selected by the user is in: 'ui.item.value'
}});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the keyup event handler works exactly the way I wanted!

Comment: Could you also help me how to display the returned data in a html div?

Comment: sure you just need to do: `$("#the_id_of_the_div").html(data);` in the success function

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $('#city').change(function() {

        var formdata = $('#term').val() 

        $.ajax({
            url: "/suggestjson",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'term': formdata},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }   
        }); 

        return false;
    });
```

Or

```
 $('#city').keyup(function() { 
     ........
     .......
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the keyup event handler I needed all along!